# Using required controller in controller - not link

Tags: angularjs

When using `require: "^directive1"` in `directive2` You can access it's variables and function in link function `link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {}` - ctrl is directive's 1 controller.
How to use `ctrl` in `controller` - not `link` func?

Comment: Why you want `ctrl` inside controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found perfect solution for my issue:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$element', function($element) {
   var parentCtrl = $element.parent().controller('diective1');
}])
```

source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10998#issuecomment-73308256

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything that can be shared between the controllers? Yes, there is: the directives can share the same `scope`!

You need to expose the controller on the shared `scope` object. The simplest way to do that is in the `link` function of your second directive:

```
var linkFn = function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  scope.exposedCtrl = ctrl;
};
```

As long as you're not using isolated scopes, you should be able to access `$scope.exposedCtrl` in your parent directive. Just remember that the `exposedCtrl` property won't be initialized until the child directive's link function has been called.

Comment: Problem is that controller func is triggered before link func:/ http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: That's not a problem, you just need to be defensive in your use of the `exposedCtrl` property. So, maybe instead of setting it directly on the scope, you call a function that you define on the controller, ex. `scope.setChildCtrl(ctrl);`. That way you know when it's being set and can handle accordingly.